# create a "POST" form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am not sure how to create a POST form.  I currently have a form that takes users input and create an entry in my movies table.  I want to have a button that takes a set of given attributes and is added to the table once a user only clicks a button.

In my searches controller I have:

```
def index
  @movie = Movie.new   
end
```

This is in the index view of searches:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@movie, :url => { :action => "create" }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "Skyfall" } %>
    <%= f.input :year, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "2012" } %>
    <%= f.input :description, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "James Bond" } %>
    <%= f.association :genres, include_blank: false, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "some value" } %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-warning" %>
<% end %>
```

Currently it routes to [http://localhost:3000/search.4]  Ideally I want it to route to [http://localhost:3000/movies/4]

routes:

```
   searches GET    /searches(.:format)          searches#index
            POST   /searches(.:format)          searches#create
 new_search GET    /searches/new(.:format)      searches#new
edit_search GET    /searches/:id/edit(.:format) searches#edit
     search GET    /searches/:id(.:format)      searches#show
            PUT    /searches/:id(.:format)      searches#update
            DELETE /searches/:id(.:format)      searches#destroy
     movies GET    /movies(.:format)            movies#index
            POST   /movies(.:format)            movies#create
  new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)        movies#new
 edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)   movies#edit
      movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)        movies#show
            PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)        movies#update
            DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)        movies#destroy
     search GET    /search(.:format)            movies#search
     genres GET    /genres(.:format)            genres#index
            POST   /genres(.:format)            genres#create
  new_genre GET    /genres/new(.:format)        genres#new
 edit_genre GET    /genres/:id/edit(.:format)   genres#edit
      genre GET    /genres/:id(.:format)        genres#show
            PUT    /genres/:id(.:format)        genres#update
            DELETE /genres/:id(.:format)        genres#destroy
       root        /                            movies#index
```

routes.rb

```
Movies::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :searches
  resources :movies
  get 'search', to: 'movies#search', as: :search

  resources :genres
  root :to => 'movies#index'
end
```

Comment: Please show us the routes defined for this create action. I think that is the problem.

Comment: edited question with routes

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that that route is being used based off the rake routes output. Can you show the contents of Config/routes.rb instead please?

Comment: It's still not making sense. Are you sure you're showing the right form? That form should be generating a URL like /movies, not /searches

Comment: yeah.  it doesn't make any sense to me.  I have it online https://github.com/emailnitram/movies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are calling it from the Search controller/views, try something like:

```
<%= simple_form_for @movie do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= simple_form_for @movie, url: movie_path(@movie) do |f| %>
```

or worst scenario (because it will be a fixed path):

```
<%= simple_form_for @movie, url: movies_path, method: post do |f| %>
```

Comment: I went with the last suggestion.  That worked.  Thanks a lot!